# How does Parse calculate the total number of requests?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

How does Parse calculate the total number of requests?

I sent around 30 query requests to test my app. After each query, Parse sent a push notification. But, in my dashboard I only see "13 requests" in total.

Considering the query requests and the push requests, shouldn't it have been more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul,

Virtually anything you do in Parse is counted against you in terms of an API request, I think the only thing that isn't counted against you is cached data, which makes sense since it already used an API request to obtain. So if your using `kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork`, you potentially won't sacrifice an additional request only provided you have something cached. This includes the new local datastore, some things you do with local datastore count against you as well.

You can review their FAQ for reference for a thorough breakdown on their allowances, see the section titled 'What is Considered An API Request'. It literally leaves no room for assumption or misinterpretation :

> Anytime you make a network call to Parse on behalf of your app using one of the Parse SDKs or REST API, it counts as an API request. This does include things like queries, saves, logins, amongst other kinds of requests. It also includes requests to send push notifications, although this is seen as a single request regardless of how many recipients are targeted. Serving Parse files counts as an API request, including static assets served from Parse Hosting. Analytics requests do have a special exemption. You can send us your analytics events any time without being limited by your app's request limit.

It's in your best interest to assume everything you do will be counted against you. This will lead you to smarter infrastructure if your app is scaleable.

But below that reference it goes on to explain that Parse requests are actually calculated on a per minute basis. I have an app that can make more than 30 requests per second, but won't max out because it doesn't reach the 1800 per minute limit.

**REFERENCE :** https://parse.com/plans/faq